# New line in not working in JavaScript alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

Html:

```
<p id="value">
 Challange Accepted.\nTested Ok
</p>
```

js:

```
var result = jQuery('#value').text();
var response = String(result);
alert(response);
```

My fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/prg5h1zy/15/#&togetherjs=Rx9GCd4GAs

Comment: Using a <br> seems to work

Comment: Just using a regular newline will work as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace `\n` text with `\n` that behave like a new line:

```js
var result = jQuery('#value').text();
var response = result.replace(/\\n/g,"\n");
alert(response);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="value">
 Challange Accepted.\nTested Ok
</p>
```

Comment: it says i need to wait 9 minutes to accept an answer.